# Getting past locations with CoreLocation CLLocationManager

Tags: ios, core-location

I want to write a iOS app where I can defer getting locations till I ask for it. Lets say I start tracking the user location updates, I want to get the locations the users have been the next time I wake up the app. I thought there was a way to get this from CoreLocation but I am unable to find the appropriate methods. Please help! thanks!

Comment: you must make an array in which you append the the user lat and long, when user change the location. By doing this way, you maintain all the previous lat and long of user which is very effective.

Comment: no this means that it is constantly getting locations. I seem to remember that there is a way to get locations for a given time.. once a certain API is called.. I cant find it right now.

Comment: Ok thats great Man

Answer (score 0):

Found it it is asking CoreLocation to do deferred location update.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620547-allowdeferredlocationupdates

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this by calling:

`locationManager.disallowDeferredLocationUpdates()`

It should cancel the deferral of location updates for your app and deliver all pending locations

More information in the [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620565-disallowdeferredlocationupdates).